# how do i change the orientation in android

Tags: android, orientation

I want to swich the orientation of an app (without the user turning the phone.) How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within an activity, you can do

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Or the following for portrait:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Cool! I thought this was impossible.

Comment: Is there a way to change the orientation to its self so that it will restart the activity?